# Default Table Model in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, defaulttablemodel

I have encountered some problem when trying to select single row from table view in JavaFX.

Here is how I populate my table with data from database:

```
public void populateCategoryTable() {
    data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    try {
        db.getConnection();
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM sm_category";
        ResultSet rs = null;
        // Call readRequest to get the result
        rs = db.readRequest(sql);

        while (rs.next()) {
            ObservableList<String> row = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            //All the rows are added here dynamically 
            row.add(rs.getString("categoryID"));
            data.add(row);
        }
        viewCategory.setItems(data);
        rs.close();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Error SQL!!!");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    TableColumn id = new TableColumn("ID");
    id.setVisible(false);
    id.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
        public ObservableValue<String> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, String> param) {
            return new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().get(0).toString());
        }
    });

    viewCategory.getColumns().addAll(id);

    TableView.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION); //Error here
    TableView.TableViewSelectionModel selectionModel = viewCategory.getSelectionModel();
    ObservableList selectedCells = selectionModel.getSelectedCells();
    TablePosition tablePosition = (TablePosition) selectedCells.get(0);
    int row = tablePosition.getRow(); // yields the row that the currently selected cell is in

}
```

However, when I tried to insert the setSelectionMode code, there is an error. It tells me that **cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method setSelectionMode(int)
  location: class TableView**

I remember when I did table in JavaSwing, I used this to set a model for table: DefaultTableModel tableModel = (DefaultTableModel) jTable.getModel();

However, I cannot do this in javaFX. Anybody could help me fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default selection mode of tableview is `SelectionMode.SINGLE`. To change it to multiple try

```
tableView.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
```

***>** what am I trying to do is select a single row from table and get the index*

To get selected index:

```
viewCategory.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
```

To listen changes of index:

```
viewCategory.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
        System.out.println("index changed from " + oldValue + " to " + newValue);
    }
});
```

Comment: I got an error message after changing the code: non-static method getSelectionModel() cannot be referenced from a static context
  where S is a type-variable:
    S extends Object declared in class TableView. Also, I've found what property style to code for table view. Am I supposed to use the so called 'property' style thingy?

Comment: Do `myTableViewInstance.getSelectionModel()` not `TableView.getSelectionModel()`. What do you mean by "property style"?

Comment: I get it from this website and I found it's complicated. http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html. What is myTableViewInstance by the way? It's not declared

Comment: Am I supposed to write addListSelectionListener like Java Swing? Because what am I trying to do is select a single row from table and get the index

Comment: Hmm.. the correct one in your case is `viewCategory.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);`. Don't be confused with `SelectionMode` and `SelectionModel`. They are different things. You can find this out in the link you mentioned.

Comment: Oh so I did wrongly for the previous one. Sorry because I thought that one is the code to select row in table. So after I selected a row, the newValue = index of selected row?

Comment: @Carol. Exactly. Or you can get the getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex() directly in button actio for example.

Comment: But it start from -1 and it screwed up all my other part. Is there any way to make it start with 1?

Comment: -1 means UNSELECTED, which is default at start up. Check the index with `if(getSelectedIndex() > -1)` or in listener `if(newValue > -1)`.

Comment: oh no no I mean it starts with 0. But my data inside database start with 1. So it does not match. And I cant write like newValue++; as it is a Number data type

Comment: @Carol. Please ask your further questions in new threads. The index of arrays and lists in most programming languages (including Java and hence JavaFX) starts with 0. The DB data is data, it can be anything. Don't mix them.

Comment: I think you misunderstand my question and I also get quite blur just now. What I am trying to do is get the first column value of selected row. It's not getting the index of selected row